# ASP.NET Core Select Helper Throws Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've created an ASP.NET Core web application that uses Entity Framework Core to read from my existing database.  I want to populate a select control with a list of FacilityNames in a view to create a new entry in my FacilityRevenue table.

My Create method on the FacilityRevenue Controller is as follows:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
       PopulateFacilityDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    private void PopulateFacilityDropDownList
    (object selectedFacility = null)
    {
        var facilityQuery = from f in _context.FacilityMaster
                            orderby f.FacilityName
                            select f;
        ViewBag.FacilityID = new SelectList(facilityQuery.AsNoTracking(), "FacilityID", "FacilityName", selectedFacility);
    }
```

My Create view includes the following markup:

```
        <label asp-for="FacilityName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="FacilityId" asp-items="ViewBag.FacilityID">
                <option value="">-- Select Facility --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="FacilityName" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
```

My FacilityRevenue Model is as follows:

```
 public partial class FacilityRevenue
{
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalInvoices { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalRevenue { get; set; }
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int? FacilityId { get; set; }

    public virtual FacilityMaster Facility { get; set; }
}
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.Eval(Object container, 
String expression)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.
GetListItemsWithValueField()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.
GenerateGroupsAndOptions(String optionLabel, IEnumerable`1 selectList,  
ICollection`1 currentValues)
at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.
DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateSelect(ViewContext viewContext, ModelExplorer 
modelExplorer, String optionLabel, String expression, IEnumerable`1 
selectList, ICollection`1 currentValues, Boolean allowMultiple, Object 
htmlAttributes)
at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext 
context, TagHelperOutput output)
at   
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.
ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.
<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

How do I remedy the above error and achieve the functionality of hydrating the select control with a list of facilities?

Comment: The error is because `ViewBag.FacilityID` is `null` (probably because you submit the form, then return the view but forgot to repopulate the `ViewBag` property. But never use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`

Comment: +1 for a question that only obliquely solved my problem: your `facilityQuery` returns the entire object, not specific fields, which is what I was doing (resulting in the same error message). I needed to return at least a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is a typo in the following line:

```
ViewBag.FacilityID = new SelectList(facilityQuery.AsNoTracking(), "FacilityID", "FacilityName", selectedFacility);
```

`"FacilityID"` must be `"FacilityId"`. That is what you defined in your model:

```
public int? FacilityId { get; set; }
```

Comment: And this may help other people to: In my case I had a "BookID" when in fact the field was simply called "ID" as this was my default model.

Comment: thanks mate i was beating my heads up for 1/2 hours ....just a simple whitespace caused me this much trouble

Comment: Wow. How did we survive before StackOverflow?!

Comment: I just want to make this point in case I end up searching this issue again with the same problem.  It may look like your SelectList is setup properly so you may think you don't need to check the spelling of the properties in your SelectList.  You may think this because when you debug and check your SelectList it has a collection of items but when  you try to use it in your cshtml you'll get a null reference.  Instead, you need to make sure your "Results View" property of the SelectList returns results, if it doesn't, you mis-spelled one of your properties like what is mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just post my fix after getting the same error as this by reading people's suggestions. Please avoid **typo variable name in the .cshtml file** for **SelectList of asp-items**. In my case, it's just *a blank space* before the variable name of *dataValueField of the SelectList*, it causes the exception. I am using Asp.net Core 3.0 MVC.
Here is the code example:
The exception happened for this code:

```
<select id="dropdownLessons" class="form-control" asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.LessonDisplays, " Id", "LessonInformationString" ))">
<option selected>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

The code fix is just to remove a blank space before "Id", then it works!

```
<select id="dropdownLessons" class="form-control" asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.LessonDisplays, "Id", "LessonInformationString" ))">
<option selected>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for reading it.